# Pressing Tab Does Not Select Next Control | Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Tab was working but now when I press tab the next control on the custom view wont select. Do you know why tab is not selecting the next control?

Note, autoRecalculatesKeyViewLoop on the parent Nib is TRUE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to connect the `nextKeyView` outlet from the "source view" to the next view in Interface Builder:

[image: nextKeyView]

Cool thing about this is that you can overwrite the default behavior.